# How to receive a PHP Table on AJAX, and display it inside a DIV?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I'm beginning to work with AJAX, and I'm struggling with the next few things.
I'm working in Wordpress, with custom tables.
By the way, that's why the global $wpdb is there.

First, I have a Select, when you choose an option, the ID value will get stored in a variable in jQuery. This is done by the

```
onchange="selectRequest(this)"


global $wpdb;
$Estado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM cor_estado;");
?>
<p>Busqueda por Estado</p>
<select class="select" id="estado" name="estado" value="" type="text" onchange="selectRequest(this);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un estado...</option>
    <?php 
    foreach ($Estado as $Estados ) {
        echo "<option value='".$Estados->estado_id."' type='text'>".$Estados->nombre_estado."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

The Select will fill up with the id on value and the name.

This is my jQuery, but I'm having a problem here, if I leave everything on the jQuery(document).ready(){CODE HERE}, the Function selectRequest(id), won't work at all, I don't know if that has anything to do with the way that I am getting the id from the select.

Here it changed, now I am trying to receive HTML, I created the complete table on "table.php", and now I am trying to get it back

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function selectRequest(id){ // id of select
    var selectVal = jQuery(id).val(); // currently selected 
    selectVal = selectVal.toString();
    alert(selectVal);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",  
        url:"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/table.php",   
        dataType: "html",  
        data:{selectVal:selectVal},
         success:function(resultHtml){ 
            jQuery("#resultado").html(resultHtml);
        },
        error:function(resultHtml){   
            alert("What follows is blank: " + data);
        }  
       });  
    }
</script>
```

my PHP is like this at the moment, one big change was in the WHERE, since I am using an INNER JOIN, I needed to specify on which table the "estado_id" was going to be, since Wordpress uses table prefix, it was necessary to add it in this place too.

Like I said before, I decided to build the table here, and send it to AJAX with an echo, I created $table, and each time something was created inside the table, I added it with ".=".

Testing this inside the table.php without the "If(isset($_post['selectVal']))", and having an static ID it worked on the table.php document, but if I echo $table, I get nothing on AJAX, it appears as blank.

```
    <?php  
 //table.php  
 global $wpdb;
 if(isset($_POST["selectVal"])){ 
    $Estado_id = $_POST["selectVal"];
     $Estado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM cor_municipio INNER JOIN cor_estado ON cor_municipio.estado_id = cor_estado.estado_id WHERE cor_estado.estado_id = $Estado_id;");
       $table = "<table>";
        $table .="<thead>";
            $table .="<tr>";
                $table .="<th>Municipio</th>";
                $table .="<th>Estado</th>";
            $table .="</tr>";
        $table .="</thead>";
       $table .="<tbody>";
    foreach ($Estado as $row) {
        $table .="<tr>";
        $table .="<td>".$row->nombre_municipio."</td>";
        $table .="<td>".$row->nombre_estado."</td>";
        $table .="</tr>";
    }
        $table .="</tbody>";
    $table .="</table>";
    echo $table;
}
 ?>
```

This is the HTML div where I want to display the echo $table content. At the moment if I select an option, the only thing that happens is that the P element disappears.

```
    <div id="resultado">
      <p>Estado Seleccionado</p>
    </div>
```

The new problem is receiving this echo $table and displaying it where AJAX receives it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the basic problem here was that I was following the steps to do this using the tools (JS, PHP, HTML and CSS) outside the Wordpress environment, this was the issue. I'm still solving some aspects about my AJAX request, I will try to update this answer as fast as I can.

[In this Wordpress Codex entry, they explain it in detail.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Basically Wordpress has it's own way of using AJAX, so no matter if this 'looked' correct to me, the Wordpress site wasn't going to display anything from it.

Here is the solution that I used to solve my problem.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
UPDATED CODE
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#estado').change(function() {
    var selectVal = jQuery('option:selected').val();
    selectVal = selectVal.toString();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/cors/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",   
        type:"POST", 
        data:{action:'my_action', selectVal: selectVal},
        success:function(data){
            jQuery("#municipio_result").hide(500);
            jQuery("#municipio_result").removeData();
            jQuery("#municipio_result").html(data);
            jQuery("#municipio_result").show(500);
            },
       });  
    });
});
```

### STEP #1

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php //will be the URL for all your custom AJAX requests.

This is absolutely necessary, because this document verifies the AJAX 'actions', and points them to your functions.php

### STEP #2

data:{action:'your_action_name', val1: 1, val2: 2 ...}

The first variable that you have to send will always be action, the value can be the anything you want.

As I said earlier, admin-ajax.php looks for the variable action when it receives an AJAX request from any file, it will look for action, once it finds it, it will redirect it to the functions.php file located inside your_theme folder.

### STEP #3

Inside you functions.php file, you will add the PHP code as a function, like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

 function selectEstado(){
 global $wpdb;
 if(isset($_POST["selectVal"])){ 
    $Estado_id = $_POST["selectVal"];
     $Estado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM cor_municipio INNER JOIN cor_estado ON cor_municipio.estado_id = cor_estado.estado_id WHERE cor_estado.estado_id = $Estado_id;");
       $table = "<table>";
        $table .="<thead>";
            $table .="<tr>";
                $table .="<th>Municipio</th>";
                $table .="<th>Estado</th>";
            $table .="</tr>";
        $table .="</thead>";
       $table .="<tbody>";
    foreach ($Estado as $row) {
        $table .="<tr>";
        $table .="<td>".$row->nombre_municipio."</td>";
        $table .="<td>".$row->nombre_estado."</td>";
        $table .="</tr>";
    }
        $table .="</tbody>";
        $table .="</table>";
        echo $table;
        wp_die(); 
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'selectEstado');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'selectEstado');
```

### STEP #4

Inside your functions.php file you will create a function, can be called whatever you want, for example 'your_function_name'.

To access easily to the database, Wordpress uses the variable $wpdb, by including the line like this global $wpdb; now you can use it to access the database without any problems.

Now you have to check if the values after action got there, the if(isset($_POST)) will take care of it. To check the Database, you use the $wpdb->get_result("");

Basically what I am doing with the INNER JOIN, is checking a column name, and checking where the two tables match, and then pulling the rest of the columns that the element on the table has in "cor_municipio" and "cor_estado".

(In this code I am using JOINS, if you want to know more about them, I'll leave a link below)

[Here they explain JOINS with Venn diagrams](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Then I created a variable that each time a part of the table was created, it was being added to it.

You echo your data, and don't forget "wp_die();"

### STEP #5

This is the last part to have your AJAX request working on Wordpress.

The next two lines are very important for it to work, this is the action that admin-ajax.php is looking for, and it's here that it references it's value, these lines look like this for every new AJAX request you need to make:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_', '');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_', '');
```

this is the "default" way the lines are written, but you will need to complete them with two things.

- The action value you used in the AJAX request, in my case is 'my_action', or in this example 'your_action_name'.
- The second value is the name of the function created inside your functions.php file.

It will end up looking like this for me:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'selectEstado');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'selectEstado');
```

Using the value of 'your_action_name' and 'your_function_name':

```
add_action('wp_ajax_your_action_name', 'your_function_name');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_action_name', 'your_function_name');
```

The first line is for logged in users, and the second one is for visitors, if you want to display something different for logged in users and another one for visitors, you will need to create a function for each of them, and just use one attribute.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_your_action_name', 'your_function_name1'); // for registered users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_action_name', 'your_function_name2'); // for visitors
```

Again, this is PHP code written in admin-ajax.php, if you want to look deeper into it.

I already found out my problem, when I was sending the data on the first time I was using:

```
data:{action:'my_action', selectVal: 'selectVal'},
```

Basically what I was sending to Wordpress on selectVal, was the string

```
selectVal
```

So when my function tried to find the id based on the receiving data, it wasn't going to find anything, because it was a string with those letter.

SOLUTION

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#estado').change(function() {
    var selectVal = jQuery('option:selected').val();
    selectVal = selectVal.toString();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/cors/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",   
        type:"POST", 
        data:{action:'my_action', selectVal: selectVal}, // The right way to send it
        success:function(data){
            jQuery("#municipio_result").hide(500);
            jQuery("#municipio_result").removeData();
            jQuery("#municipio_result").html(data);
            jQuery("#municipio_result").show(500);
            },
       });  
    });
});
```

What I am sending now is the value, and now my AJAX success:function, receives the complete table, I also changed the jQuery code, because in the first example, when adding ".hide() or .show()", it was sending multiple errors.

To add conditions by user role you can edit the admin-ajax.php to make it simpler for all the AJAX requests.

I know is way too long, but if you were having some trouble, I wanted to explain all the different elements that are used, to make it easier to understand what is happening with AJAX in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

instead of receiving data in JSON format, use HTML formatted data & replace your data directly in table. Using that your base issue **"the amount of information in them will be different on each select option"** will be resolved.

Comment: Hi!, I've tried what you told me, and it makes sense, based on the issue, but I do not know how to receive the table that I created on my PHP file, but your approach to the issue helped me to understand a little bit better how this works.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a fixed rule... Sometimes is faster to create the html in the php and return it formatted so you can show it directly and sometimes is better to return raw data and handle it in javascript/jquery.

If the data you get from the ajax request is just for showing and you don't need to modify anything that depends of other elements in your current view, I will format the html response directly in the php. If you need to change something, then maybe I will go with JSON.

In your ajax request you establish JSON as the data format, so the response in your PHP has to be JSON. You almost have it. Uncomment the foreach but instead of independent variables ($info1, $info2) create an array with the fields you need for your response, and set key names. For example...

```
$response = array();

foreach ($Estado as $row) {
    $response['municipio'] = $row->nombre_municipio;
    $response['estado'] = $row->nombre_estado;
    .....
}
```

Once you have the array created, convert it to JSON and return with...

print_r(json_encode($response));

Then, in your jquery ajax success function you can access each field with...

```
data.municipio or data['municipio']
data.estado or data['estado']
...
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi!, thanks a lot, this really helped me to understand what was going on, but now I'm faced with a new problem. I decided to build the table on the php file, because the array wasn't working for me, however, now I can't display the response, and it gets to AJAX empty.

Comment: @JuanOMtz Mmm... strange... Let's check some stuff...
1. Do an alert("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/table.php") before the ajax, and chechk the route is correct.
2. So, just to confirm, when you access the table.php file directly in your browser (tweaking the if and the post...) you get the right <table>, right? So, with this we are sure that the query and the table creation process is ok.
3. It looks like your getting a success answer, because your div is written. Just to be sure, do an alert(resultHtml) inside of success to check.

Comment: @JuanOMtz 4. Do you have access to the web server log? If so, check that he's receiving the ajax call to the right file, or if it's showing some error.
5. Are you getting some error in the browser javascript console?
Ohh! Maybe the selectVal name repetition is messing jQuery up... use different names for the Ajax variable in the data object and for your local variable.

Comment: I figured it out. It turns out that this is correct, BUT as I am doing this AJAX function in a Wordpress Environment, I needed to use the admin-ajax.php file that Wordpress has built in the system.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

In this link explains how to use it and connect it to you WP AJAX requests.

Comment: Wordpress strikes again!! Jajaja (I've never used it). Your last description was looking ok to me, so makes sense that is a Wordpress thing. Glad to here you solve it!
If you don't mind, put the solution in the post or as an answer, so everybody can learn from it.
Have a nice day and happy coding!